Manuals of structuralist text analysis
I have studied mathematics and philology. For years my main problem is to find a method -specific, strict and clear- of text analysis. In the context of my readings I was attracted to structuralism. I read Greimas, Tesnier, Mel'cuk (dependency is a structural approach) etc., I found an ocean of general words about structuralism as a theory but I never found a book analyzing texts step by step with this method!
Is anybody aware of the reason of absence of books containing a step by step structural analysis of texts and/or developing strictly such a method? If this absence is a fact, then why should we talk about structuralism in literature criticism?

You need to use a different search term: structural literary criticism or critics, like Roland Barthes. In translation but still good. However, I don't know any textbooks like that (rather than manuals, in English). Like Writing Degree Zero OR S/Z [fyi, we don't use philology so much in English. It corresponds to what we call language and literary studies)

Isn't it strange that we cannot find such works? Any book on history of literature spends some space about structuralism, but we have not applications of this method!

Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Questions about literary analysis, theory and criticism are obviously on topic here, but open-ended requests for suggestions are not. Those are better asked in our Reading Room. That said, literary analysis, even when based on structuralism, does not proceed according to an algorithm or a recipe, so you'll need to read some theory and a few examples and then dive in ...

https://www.ccsenet.org/journal/index.php/ells/article/view/0/42153 You just have to search more thoroughly. And: https://ojs.ahss.org.pk/journal/article/view/436 are two examples.
